# GnuPG with CAPI smartcard / NOT an OpenPGP card

Tags: git, gnupg, digital-signature, openpgp, token

I have a RSA SecurId loaded with two keys and their corresponding certificate (signature and authentication).

I'm already using the authentication key pair for SSH login (from my Windows desktop) thanks to [Putty CAC](https://risacher.org/putty-cac/) and I was wondering if the same could be done for GnuPG/OpenPGP keys.

My ultimate goal is signing git commits and tag using my secure key.

I must stress out that this kind of key **is not** an [OpenPGP Card](http://www.g10code.de/p-card.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GnuPG does not support non-OpenPGP-smartcards. While generally this should be possible (in the end, the smartcard only holds the plain numbers of the private keys together with some meta data, but no complete OpenPGP keys), it is not implemented in GnuPG (and I'm neither aware of any other OpenPGP implementation supporting arbitrary smart cards).

But there are some examples for USB security tokens (which are no smartcards) implementing the OpenPGP smartcard interface: I am aware of at least the YubiKey and Nitro Key in some editions.

Answer (score -1):

See (namely gnupg-pkcs11-scd) https://www.flyn.org/notes/smartcard/index.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please [**edit your answer**](//superuser.com/posts/1333793/edit) so it contains that information. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Answer] page, to better familiarise yourself with this site.